# Spring boot CrudRepository Insert data into database

Tags: spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and I am trying to insert a record into a database but it's not working.

DOA Code. **DAO Interface**

```
public interface DAO<T, ID>{

Optional<T> find(ID id) throws SQLException;
boolean sava(T o) throws SQLException;
boolean update(T o) throws SQLException;
boolean deleteData(T o) throws SQLException;

}
```

Below is the code I am using to insert the record. **UserRepository interface**

```
public interface UserRepository extends DAO<User, Long>, CrudRepository<User, Long> {

  @Override
@Modifying
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO User (userID, firstName, lastName, gender, dateOfBirth, age, phoneNum, email) " +
        "values (:userID, :firstName, :lastName, :gender, :dateOfBirth, :age, :phoneNum, :email)", nativeQuery = true)
default boolean sava(User user) throws SQLException { 
    return true;
};
}
```

**UserService class**

```
@Service
public class UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

public boolean save (User user) throws SQLException {
    return userRepository.sava(user);
}
}
```

**Get RequestMapping in the controller class**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user_register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getUserRegistration(@ModelAttribute User user, Model model) {
    user.setUserID((long) utilService.generateRandomNumber());
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    System.out.println("Get user registration form");
    return "/UserRForm";
}
```

Post RequestingMapping in the controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/process_u_register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postUserRegistration(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("user id is.... " + user.getUserID());
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "/UserRForm";
    }
    // For testing to making sure I am getting the right url
    System.out.println(user.toString());
    boolean inserted = userService.save(user);
    if (!inserted) {
        return "/UserRForm";
    };
    return "redirect:/address";
}
```

I did a test for invalid input and the form did not submit. And then I did another test for valid values and the form did submit and called the toString with all the values without any errors. But in the database the data is not there. And spring boot / CrudRepository is not throwing any errors to indicate that the record did not get inserted.

Comment: You don't need a `sava` function to write the SQL insert statement, this is handled by the `CrudRepository`, simply use `userRepository.save(user)`.

Comment: I change the save method in DAO interface to saveDAO and I Override the save method in CrudRepository in UserRepository interface and used that method and it work. Thank!!!!. But is there a way that I can Override the save method and write my own insert query statement instead of the default one CrudRepository provide

Comment: which type of database you are using??

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It MySQL database